# phpexcel use variable for a dynamic range area

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to create a dynamic range to scan value from an Excel sheet. The code that I use is:

```
 $tipo2 =  $col1= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('C'.$i:'E'.$i)
```

But `rangeToArray ('C'. $i:'E'. $i)` gives me back an error.
Do you know how I can use a variable for a dynamic range area?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: PHP 101 - [String concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rangeToArray('C'.$i.':E'.$i)
```